# cast from templated derived class to template base class

Tags: c++, templates, casting, derived

I am implementing a shared_pointer template that holds a pointer to typename T
I want to implement a copy-constructor (with a pointer of a Base class (T)) that receives a shared pointer class (that holds a pointer to a Derived class(O)).
How can i cast the received pointer to shared_ptr from Base type?

```
template <typename T>
class Shared_Ptr
{
public:
    template <typename O>friend class Shared_Ptr;    
    template <typename O>
    Shared_Ptr(const Shared_Ptr<O>& other_);
private:
    struct PtrVal
    {
        PtrVal(T* ptr);
        ~PtrVal();
        T *m_ptr;
        size_t m_count;
    };

    PtrVal *m_val;  
};
```

How can I implement the Copy-Constructor??

```
template <typename T>
template <typename O>
Shared_Ptr<T>::Shared_Ptr(const Shared_Ptr<O>& other_): 
m_val(static_cast<const Shared_Ptr<T> >(other_).m_val)
{}
```

This compiles but gives Segmentation fault (core dumped) at run time.

I've found another solution but it is really ugly:
I convert m_ptr of other_ to T* (instead of O*) and then cast m_val of O to m_val of T

```
Shared_Ptr<T>::Shared_Ptr(const Shared_Ptr<O>& other_)
{
    if(dynamic_cast<T *>(other_.m_val->m_ptr))
    {}

    m_val = (Shared_Ptr<T>::PtrVal *)other_.m_val;
}
```

Any suggestions to something better?
Thank you

Comment: have a look in the source code for boost::shared_ptr and std::shared_ptr. You'll see that the deleter is also stored in the control block (which is important for type-erasure).

Comment: You should be more accurate with terminology, what you call copy ctor is not one.

Answer (score 1):

You want to cast `m_ptr`, not `other_` because `Shared_Ptr<O>` and `Shared_Ptr<T>` have no inheritance relationship.

```
template <typename T>
template <typename O>
Shared_Ptr<T>::Shared_Ptr(const Shared_Ptr<O>& other_):
    m_val (static_cast<T*>(other_.m_val->m_ptr))
{}
```

You will also have to update the counter.

Comment: Not a good idea, this will allow pointer to base converted to derived, which should not happen.

Comment: @Slava I agree this is a bad idea as there is no type checking. I merely answer to the question that was asked. Maybe shkopa knows what he does when he calls this "cast constructor".

Comment: Then you answered incorrectly, because without `static_cast` it could work as it should.

Comment: You mean `m_val (other_.m_val->m_ptr)` ? If yes, this will never do the downcast.